# Express validator validate if data provided

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I'm using express-validator for validation for mandatory fields. But some fields are not mandatory like date of birth, price. I want to validate if these fields contains a value, like if I provide the date of birth value, then it must be of date type. I've checked every tutorials, docs & tried almost everything, but failed. How to validate fields when it contains value. Custom method is the last option to try. can i make it without custom method?

Comment: make a [custom](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html) one `body('birth').custom(birth => !birth || moment(birth).isValid())` etc

Comment: can it be done using existing methods in express-validator without using custom ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `optional` and checkFalsy. This will only run the `isISO8601()` validation on the `dateOfBirth` field if not is null, undefined, 0, false, or empty string

```
check('dateOfBirth').optional({ checkFalsy: true }).isISO8601()
```

Comment: Marked it as accepted, cant mark it as useful because i dont have 15 reputation